# Fatal error: Call to undefined function validation_errors() in

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, view, controller

Here is the code:

```
class CCI extends Controller {

 function CCI()
 {
  parent::Controller();
 }

 function index()
 {
   $this->load->helper('url');
  $this->load->view('Users/login');
 }

 function test()
 {
  echo "Testing Data";
 }
}
```

The page was loading fine until I moved the location of the "login" page inside of the "Users" folder

Answer (score 1):

Well then probably change

```
$this->load->view('Users/login');
```

to

```
$this->load->view('login');
```

Since you moved the file inside the Users folder you need to adjust paths for that.

Answer (score 1):

You're properly displaying any validation errors within your view using the '**validation_errors**' function that's located in the '**form_helper**'. Load the 'form_helper' as well and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Add following two lines of code to the controller:

```
$this->load->helper('form');
$this->load->library('form_validation');
```